# How do I create Boundary Polygons using Data-driven Styling, after PlaceFeature.displayName has been deprecated? - JavaScript Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have a website that uses Google Maps API to create a map, with one random country being highlighted at a time. The way I currently highlight a country is using [data-driven styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/overview) to create [boundary polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/style-polygon):

[Example of how the map should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHYkC.png)

But, Google recently started throwing errors, saying that the **[`displayName`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data-driven-styling#PlaceFeature.displayName)** property (which I use) could no longer be used as of February 2023. Here's a snippet of how my code looked before the change:

```js
featureLayer.style = (options) => {
  if (options.feature["displayName"] == "Italy") {
    return featureStyleOptions;
  }
};
```

In the official explanation, the **[`fetchPlace()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data-driven-styling#PlaceFeature.fetchPlace)** function should just be used as a replacement, [because the fetchPlace() function also returns the displayName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XosDJ.png).

But fetchPlace() can't be used in a synchronous function (it only returns promises), so I tried rewriting the code. In this attempt I used the .then() method, but now it doesn't apply the boundary polygons at all:

```js
featureLayer.style = (options) => {
  options.feature.fetchPlace().then((Place) => {
    if (Place["displayName"] == "Italy") {
      return featureStyleOptions;
    }
  });
};
```

I only have limited knowledge of how promises/.then() work in JavaScript and how they handle the values, so I might be completely wrong with this approach.

Ideally I would just be using the **`PlaceId`** as a replacement for DisplayName, but I don't have any way of obtaining the IDs. I will appreciate any kind of help with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You could just replace `displayName` by `placeId` (Google has a [place ID finder tool](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayName` is deprecated [but not the `placeId`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data-driven-styling#PlaceFeature).

Below is an example highlighting Italy. To get the Place ID, you can use the [Place ID finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder). I have added a call to the Geocoder to be able to fit the map to the feature.

```js
let map;
let featureLayer;

function initMap() {

  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapId: "8ec1ff859561face", // You need to create your own map ID
  });

  featureLayer = map.getFeatureLayer("COUNTRY");

  // Define the styling options
  const featureStyleOptions = {
    strokeColor: "#00FF00",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#519400',
    fillOpacity: 1,
  };

  // Below Place ID is "Italy"
  let placeId = 'ChIJA9KNRIL-1BIRb15jJFz1LOI';

  geocoder.geocode({
      placeId: placeId
    })
    .then(({
      results
    }) => {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + e)
    });

  // Apply the style to a single boundary.
  featureLayer.style = (options) => {
    if (options.feature.placeId == placeId) {
      return featureStyleOptions;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=beta" defer></script>
```

Regarding `fetchPlace()`, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data-driven-styling#PlaceFeature) states:

> Do not call this from a `FeatureStyleFunction` since only synchronous `FeatureStyleFunctions` are supported.